# Are bounded groups of thin operators on Hilbert space similar to groups of unitaries?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems, similarity

**QUESTION.** Let $G$ be a group of bounded operators on $\ell^2$, satisfying $\sup_{x\in G} \lVert x\rVert <\infty$, whose elements are all of the form "identity+compact" (sometimes called "thin operators"). Is $G$ always similar, inside $B(\ell^2)$, to a group of unitary operators on $\ell^2$?

There are well-documented examples of bounded subgroups of ${\rm Inv}(B(\ell^2))$ that are not similar to unitary subgroups, but they don't seem to be contained in the space of thin operators. For example: I had a look at the examples in Pytlik–Swarc (Acta Math., 1986) but if I have understood the constructions correctly, they have the form $\pi(F)$ where $F$ is a free group and the representation $\pi: F \to {\rm Inv}(B(\ell^2(F)))$ satisfies $\pi(x)-\lambda(x)\in K(\ell^2(F))$ for all $x\in F$, so $\pi(x)-I \notin K(\ell^2(F))$ for all $x\in F \setminus \{e\}$. Nevertheless, perhaps one can modify these representations to get a negative answer to the question above?

In the other direction: if one is looking for a positive answer to the question, the closest result I could find is in [work of Miglioli+Schlicht](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06523), where the following result is obtained as Corollary 4.13.

**THEOREM** (Miglioli–Schlicht). Let $G$ be a subgroup of ${\rm Inv}(B(\ell^2))$ which satisfies $\sup_{x\in G} {\lVert I-x\rVert}_{\sf HS} <\infty$, where ${\sf HS}$ denotes the Hilbert–Schmidt norm. Then there exists $s\in {\rm Inv}(B(\ell^2))$ such that $sGs^{-1}\subseteq {\mathcal U}(\ell^2)$ (and I think that the proof shows we can get ${\lVert I-s\Vert}_{\sf HS}<\infty$).

One might hope to reduce the original question to this result by a perturbation argument, but since the Miglioli–Schlicht result requires the group to be bounded in the norm of ${\mathbb C}I + {\rm HS}(\ell^2)$, I can't see how to make this approach work.

**REMARK.** I have tagged this post "fixed-point problems" because one can reformulate unitarizability questions for groups as a fixed point property. Namely: given a unital ${\rm C}^\ast$-algebra $D$ and a subgroup $G \subset {\rm Inv}(D)$, $G$ is similar inside $D$ to a unitary subgroup if and only if there exists $h\in {\rm Inv}(D)\cap D_+$ such that $xhx^\ast=h$ for all $x\in G$. The Miglioli–Schlicht result is proved by applying the Bruhat–Tits fixed point theorem to a cone of positive operators equipped with a suitable metric.

Comment: Yemon, I assume you want your $G$ to be bounded in norm? You mention it later, but not in the question itself.

Comment: @MateuszWasilewski Oops - you are quite right. I will edit the question.

Comment: What is the motivation, since the corresponding result is false for B(H) where H is finite-dimensional? For example take any nilpotent group; this cannot be symmetric to a group of unitaries...are you saying this is the obstruction, that I+K = I in Calkin algebra? Is there a reason why groups that are U+K for another U beside I must not be similar to unitary groups, or is it just that more is known about the thin case?

Comment: @Derek: in the (corrected) version of my question, the group is supposed to be a **bounded** subset of B(H), which precludes your nilpotent example. As for my original motivation: I am interested in various problems related to the Dixmier similarity problem (and, more speculatively, the Kadison similarity problem). If that is not convincing: note that every bounded subgroup of the invertible group of a finite vN algebras is unitarizable (Vasilescu-Zsido), so it is interesting to know what other containing Cstar algebras could be used for the codomain.

Comment: @Derek: There is also the result of Day / Dixmier / Nakamura-Takeda that every bounded representation of an **amenable** group on Hilbert space is unitarizable.

Comment: Does this problem have a reformulation in terms of derivations like Kadison's similarity problem? I am asking because Popa (S. Popa: *The commutant modulo the set of  compact operators of a von Neumann algebra*) has shown that derivations with values in the compact operators are necessarily inner.

Comment: @MaoWao Sorry for the delay in responding. My question is equivalent to asking about bounded HMs from the $\ell^1$-group algebra into K(H). Kadison similarity and its variants are about bounded HMs from operator algebras into B(H) or K(H). So I don't think Kirchberg's result (DP iff SP) is going to help, since we know there are non-unitarizable HMS from $\ell^1(G)$ to B(H), and yet Kadison's similarity problem remains open.

Comment: @MaoWao In fact, my question originated in a desire to prove that every bounded HM from a Cstar algebra into K(H) is similar inside B(H) to a star-HM; a positive answer to the question in my post would imply this result. However, I have since found an alternative proof of this result concerning Cstar algebras, so the question in my post is mainly asked out of curiosity rather than because I need it for anything at the moment.